# Why does GridView load so slowly compared to a hardcoded Grid?

Tags: gridview, winrt-xaml, uwp

I've run into a UX performance issue with UWP's GridView. In my app I need to display 100-200 items in a single view (UI virtualization does not apply here). I'm finding that this GridView takes about 3 seconds to load upon first navigation to the page when compiled for Debug, and 5 seconds for a Release build (I'll save that question for another day!).

My DataTemplate is not overly complex, and I'm using x:Bind and even tried x:Phase, but no significant improvement is found. Then I tried something wacky: I made a plain old Grid and hard-coded the equivalent items and voila--load time is instantaneous. So without getting to technical, I'd guess that using a poor-man's Grid is at least 100x (or 1000x ?) faster than a GridView... to render the same content, using the same data binding.

Just to illustrate the stark contrast in performance between these two approaches, I created the most simple example: starting with this class:

```
public class Dummy
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

... with the following XAML:

```
<GridView Name="LazyContent" x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"  ItemsSource="{x:Bind Dummies}" >
                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Dummy">
                        <Border>
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Number}" />
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            </GridView>
```

... and the following code-behind:

```
public List<Dummy> Dummies { get; set; }

(in constructor)
List<Dummy> temp = new List<Dummy>();
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    temp.Add(new Dummy() { Number = i });
Dummies = temp;
```

I used lazy loading strategy and displayed a ProgressRing upon navigation to the page in question. There are 200 elements, with the simplest possible DataTemplate and model class--and the progress ring displays for 2 seconds (running on a cheap tablet). Already this is unacceptable as far as user experience goes, and this is all we're achieving:
[image: DataTemplate screenshot]

In contrast, I created another page with the same exact layout and data source, but just constructed the elements by hand, like so:

```
        <Grid Name="LazyContent" x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" >
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Dummies[0].Number}" />
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" >
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Dummies[1].Number}" />
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" >
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Dummies[2].Number}" />
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" >
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Dummies[3].Number}" />
            </Grid>

            ... you get the idea (repeat another ~200 times)
```

The result? As suspsected, the page loads instantaneously; the ProgressRing doesn't even appear. (This is running on the same cheap tablet.)

So my ultimate question is: is there a way to *drastically * improve the performance of GridView when displaying all elements all at once?

Comment: I am curious what is the `IsActive` flag of your `ProgressRing` binding to?

Comment: I just set IsActive in the code-behind right before calling FindName("LazyContent") to trigger the loading of the GridView

Comment: Keep in mind that the `GridView` control itself is a lot more complex than a `Grid`. Although the same `GridView` loads up instantaneously on my dev machine, it's never a good idea to load hundreds of items at once. I'd use *Reactive Extensions* to load say, 20 items at a time, with a `100ms` time span. With this approach, you can even achieve better UX by applying an *opacity* and *slide-up* animation to show them up gradually.

Comment: @JustinXL, thanks--I tried out your approach. Unfortunately it results in a worse situation: the GridView can't even keep up with the 100ms interval and bogs down the system so much that other collection elements on the page don't load correctly. At the end of the day, my original question stands: why is all of this staggered loading workaround even necessary in the first place? It's not like I'm loading items over a dial-up network; everything is in memory and everything is dead simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the async method to add items after the page has been loaded.

Display the page and then load all the grid items asynchronously.

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm doing

Comment: Cool... Happy Developing :)